# Windows Phone 8.1 Get Values of Custom ListView Item

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

I Have a DataTemplate for ListViewItems:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="GroupTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border Background="{ThemeResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,9.5,0,0">
                <Image Source="{Binding Property3}" Height="79" Width="79"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Margin="14.5,0,0,0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property1}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemTextBlockStyle}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Property2}" Style="{ThemeResource ListViewItemSubheaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

For my ListView:

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="systemlist" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource GroupTemplate}"  Margin="19,12,19,0" SelectionChanged="systemlist_SelectionChanged"/>
```

and create a List of Items on runtime:

```
List<fissystem> items = new List<fissystem>();
for (int i = 0; i < systems.Length; i++)
     {
          string[] parts = systems[i].Split(';');
          if (parts.Length == 3)
          {
              items.Add(new fissystem() { Property1 = parts[0], Property2 = parts[1], Property3 = parts[2] });
          }  
     }
```

The class fissystem is:

```
public class fissystem
    {
        public string Property1 { get; set; }
        public string Property2 { get; set; }
        public string Property3 { get; set; }
    }
```

How can i get the three Propertys of a selected Item in the systemlist_SelectionChange event?:

```
private void systemlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Add this code.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution in [windowsapptutorials](http://www.windowsapptutorials.com/windows-phone/data-binding/how-to-work-with-listbox-selected-item-in-windows-phone-application/)

It is possible to cast the selected Item to fissystem:

```
private void systemlist_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    fissystem item = (sender as ListView).SelectedItem as fissystem;
}
```